# The SourceSet 'source' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: c, android-gradle-plugin, java-native-interface

It's in the build.gradle file. I'm following an online course and I don't really understand what these lines of codes are doing. Probably related to "defining the path of produced so file"

```
sourceSets {
        main.jniLibs {

            source {
                srcDirs = ['../libs']
            }
        }
    }
```

The SourceSet 'source' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin. Perhaps you misspelled something?
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the expected setup

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs {
          srcDirs = ['../libs']
        }
    }
  }        
}
```